# Sending tweets from iPhone apps using Oauth

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth, sdk

Does anyone know of a good example utilizing the twitter API and Oauth authentication for iPhone SDK 2.2.1 or older?

Found an example, but it seems to utilize a 3.0 only framework at https://github.com/kimptoc/MGTwitterEngine-1.0.8-OAuth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Oauth.net website lists a couple of Objective-C implementations on their code page - http://oauth.net/code.

Comment: Thankyou, I will check out MPoauthconnection.

Comment: I managed to get things going with MPOauthConnection.  Thankyou for the link.

Answer (score 7):

This is the best solution I've found:

http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone