# how to login in twitter using oath

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am building a twitter application that is currently using the classic login instead of OAuth. I don't know how to use Oauth to implement login.Please anybody help me to provide some help regarding how to login through OAuth login

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending tweets from iPhone apps using Oauth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954236/sending-tweets-from-iphone-apps-using-oauth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be done with it as fast as possible, use Ben Gottlieb's [Twitter-OAuth-iPhone library](http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone). If you want to know exactly what happens, plan a few days to read all you can about OAuth, and then several weeks to implement.