# How to add Twitter to my iOS 5 app?

Tags: twitter, ios5

How do I integrate Twitter into my iOS 5 app? Is there an Apple Twitter API?

How should I make this backwards compatible for iOS 4?

Comment: iOS 5 APIs are under NDA. The best place to ask questions like this, assuming you're a member of the iPhone Developer Program, are here: https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/ios5beta

Comment: @John: does this really matter? Is integrating with Twitter any different for "my app" between the two? Is the question any less valid than if the "5" was removed? If anything, NDA is *between the vendor and the user*, not SO. [Meta mod says: it's fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40889/do-some-of-the-questions-answers-of-stackoverflow-break-sdk-agreements).

Comment: It's certainly possible to answer this question by pure speculation, or without breaking NDA. I'm just pointing out that the chance of getting a definitive answer is probably somewhat higher in a forum where developers may be more likely to want to talk about unannounced APIs.

Comment: Duplicates [Sending tweets from iPhone apps using Oauth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954236/sending-tweets-from-iphone-apps-using-oauth). Since you are not here to discuss any possible iOS 5-specific technology, existing questions have already fully addressed your topic.

Comment: iOS 5 is now out of beta, can we reopen this question or at least close as a duplicate of other questions instead? This page is shown at the top of google searching "ios 5 twitter", having no up-to-date answer in it is not a thing.